# Cannot create Table in Oracle using Enterprise library

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, enterprise-library, odp.net

I am create a tool to migration all data and schema from MsSqlServer to Oracle.

The .Net library used is *EntlibContrib.Data.OdpNet*.

While it execute CREATE table:

```
OracleDatabase db = new OracleDatabase(connectionString);
string createDDL = "CREATE TABLE APPInvoiceItems (ABC RAW(16));";
db.ExecuteNonQuery(createDDL);
```

I got an exception:

```
ORA-00931: missing identifier
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_UTILITY", line 156
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I have searched several topics but wasn't able to find a solution

Answer (score 1):

You appear to be calling the wrong overload of the `OracleDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery` method.

There are five overloads of this method, all inherited from [the superclass, `Database`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.practices.enterpriselibrary.data.database.executenonquery(v=pandp.31).aspx).  The overload that you are calling takes a stored procedure name and a `params` array of objects for the stored-procedure parameters.  The error arises because your DDL statement isn't a valid name for a stored procedure.

I found that using the following overload worked:

```
db.ExecuteNonQuery(CommandType.Text, createDDL);
```

(`CommandType` requires `using System.Data`.)

Additionally, you will need to remove the semicolon at the end of your DDL statement.  Otherwise you will get the error `ORA-00911: invalid character`.

Comment: You are right but not enough, we need add TABLESPACE at the end of command too. Thank you